# Title of a world hopping book, with worlds ranging magic to science

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

I can't remember anything about the characters except they were all the same person of a different universe, with variations of the same name, who were the only ones who could hop between universes. They're fighting a war for the worlds to free them from both sides, one coming from the more science-y worlds, and the other from the more magical worlds. The only thing both enemies had in common was they powered their world hopping transportation from the people who could plane-jump.

Comment: IT's sound SOMEWHAT like Piers Anthony's Split Infinity series.... But only somewhat.  Do you remember anything about how magic was accomplished?  Or something called 'The Game'?  Or a magical curtain that traversed the world they used to move from one world to the other?

Comment: @Keith for what its worth, this was my immidiate assumption as well.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the novella  "Ariel" by Lucius Shepard published in Asimov's?

A Short description (excerpt below) can be found at the Wiki site: 
http://english.turkcebilgi.com/Spring+Heeled+Jack

The first half of the full novella can be found at:
http://www.asimovs.com/_issue_0311/Ariel.shtml

In the novella "Ariel" by Lucius Shepard (published in Asimov's Science Fiction), Shepard uses Springheel Jack as the basis for his story about male and female travelers in the multiverse postulated by some versions of quantum theory, who pursue each other in infinite variations across all universes. In one universe, the lovers resemble Springheel Jack, and invade our own universe.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're thinking of Neil Gaiman's and Michael Reaves' "InterWorld." Has all the Joeys and the sentient soapbubble named Hue.

Comment: if correct, this question would be a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/198447/story-with-an-arc-of-earths-that-go-from-science-to-fantasy