# Story with an arc of Earths that go from Science to Fantasy

Tags: story-identification, audio-book

I'm looking for a story that I heard on audiobook about 10 years ago.  It was about a guy (young adult maybe?) who finds out that he can walk between planes. There are a whole arc of worlds, that range from pure science to pure magic. He is from one in the middle.

He finds that there is a version of him on every Earth, and they are the only one who can walk between the worlds.  I believe there is a scene on a flat area with a red balloon. The antagonist has a large fleet of ships.

I want to say it's called Planewalker but that didn't show anything except for Magic the Gathering books (even using the `-mtg` filter).

Comment: So, not one of these; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&OPERATOR_1=contains&TERM_1=walker&CONJUNCTION_1=AND&USE_2=title_title&OPERATOR_2=contains&TERM_2=pla&CONJUNCTION_2=AND&USE_3=title_content&OPERATOR_3=exact&TERM_3=&ORDERBY=title_title&START=0&TYPE=Title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the *Interworld* trilogy by Neil Gaiman and Michael Reaves.

Made up of *Interworld*, *The Silver Dream*, and *Eternity's Wheel*.

The guy is one Joey Harker.

Comment: In the books there is no mention of *planewalkers*, but the different worlds are called *planes* and the people who can move between them are called *Walkers* (with a capital *W*).

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you so much.  I guess that's where I got the Planeswalker thing from @JohnRennie